# write json data into .js(javascript) file?

Tags: c#, json

My current project has a .js file with hard coded data in it. So I am referencing this file and on clientside. I am using this file to get the data when ever I require on client side. But my task is to generate this .js file dynamically. I am getting my values in json format from database. SO I need a way to write this json formatted data into .js file, so I can use that written data on client side.

Needed Format in JS:

```
var list = new Array();
list["1000"] = "TestEvent1";
```

Actual Json Format:

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "event_Result"
    }, "event_id": 1000, "event_GROUPId": 17, "event_name": "TestEvent1", 
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just output it inline on the page, or use Ajax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a generic handler `ashx` that outputs javascript content.  Set your output content type to "text-javascript".

It doesn't have to have a file extension of `.js`, the content type and how it's reference is what matters

`<script type="text/javascript" src="myJavascript.ashx"></script>`

Comment: Can you tell more clear how to use handler I need to get the data in the following format:Needed Format in JS:

var list = new Array(); list["1000"] = "TestEvent1";

Actual Json Format:

{ "__metadata": { "type": "event_Result" }, "event_id": 1000, "event_GROUPId": 17, "event_name": "TestEvent1", }

Comment: with Generic Handlers, you output whatever you want, so you should output the json verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use the json encoded data by saving it into a variable or by overriding the variable that holds the initial data?